Why is the fragment container view stuck to the top left?
When I drag the frag container view unto the design view, it opens up a popup window and allows me to choose a fragment to connect the view to. I can then access the container completely on the design view, change its size, constrain it etc. After that however,
I get an error message that says "unknown fragments" and when I pick the layout myself, the container flies into the top left corner. Its for a class assignment due next week and idk what to do.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.464"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.116" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="492dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="180dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView3"
        android:name="com.example.test1.BlankFragment"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="143dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.556"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_blank" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

I've tried adding all 4 constraints, changing the constraints in the text file, nothing works.

Try this:
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView3"
        android:name="com.example.test1.BlankFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_blank" />

